# Copying file to a remote server via ftp using batch file and txt file

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I have tried these scripts
 for batch file

```
ftp -i -s:file.txt
```

And this is the txt file

```
open 127.0.0.1
SMKilonzo
kilonzo.k
Prompt n
lcd
binary
mput "*.txt"
disconnect
```

This is the output I get when I run the batch file:

[image: This is the output I get when I run the batch file]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Show us a console window screenshot after typing these commands: `dir`, `type file.txt` and `ftp -i -s:file.txt`.

Comment: What version of Windows is this?

Comment: Does not look like you are showing us all of the batch file as that single line of code would not execute multiple times.

Comment: I guess that your batch file name is either `ftp.bat` or `ftp.cmd`. You need to **rename** it to something like `myftp.bat`.

Comment: Additionally to highly recommended renaming of the batch file to something different than `ftp.bat` it would be good to replace `ftp` in batch file by `%SystemRoot%\System32\ftp.exe` because then Windows command interpreter does not need to search for `ftp.*` in current directory and in folders listed in environment variable `PATH` having a file extension listed in environment variable `PATHEXT`.